# Generating Ethereum Accounts on web3.py

Tags: web3.py, infura

I am trying to use web3.py with Infura as my HTTP Provider, and several things aren't working. I modified the example code from the web3.py Documentation to use my own contract, which is published on the Ropsten network.

My question is how do I generate an Ethereum account so that `w3.eth.accounts[0]` returns something besides an empty list? I have checked the documentation and cannot find how to do this. I have also tried replacing `w3.eth.accounts[0]` with other addresses (like my Metamask address), but this results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eugene\Documents\UCLA\Year 1\ECE 209AS\Blockchain Project\test.py", line 242, in <module>
    tx_hash = contract.deploy(transaction={'from': '0xc0615cb1a1a57422d3887fa4874958578013e842'})
  File "C:\Users\Eugene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 308, in deploy
    deploy_transaction['data'] = cls._encode_constructor_data(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Eugene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\string.py", line 108, in inner
    return force_obj_to_text(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Eugene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 749, in _encode_constructor_data
    arguments = merge_args_and_kwargs(constructor_abi, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Eugene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\string.py", line 92, in inner
    return fn(*text_args, **text_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Eugene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\web3\utils\abi.py", line 185, in merge_args_and_kwargs
    len(args) + len(kwargs),
TypeError: Incorrect argument count.  Expected '1'.  Got '0'
```

Here is my code with the abi and bytecode omitted for brevity.

```
import json
import web3

from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider, TestRPCProvider
from web3.contract import ConciseContract
# web3.py instance
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/SdO4U3ydQdgK3D3eNE2Y'))

# Instantiate and deploy contract
contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=[
...
], bytecode={
    "linkReferences": {},
    "object": "...",
    "opcodes": "...",
    "sourceMap": "..."
})

# Get transaction hash from deployed contract
tx_hash = contract.deploy(transaction={'from': w3.eth.accounts[0], 'gas': 410000})

# Get tx receipt to get contract address
tx_receipt = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
contract_address = tx_receipt['contractAddress']

# Contract instance in concise mode
# contract_instance = w3.eth.contract(contract_interface['abi'], contract_address, ContractFactoryClass=ConciseContract)
```

Answer (score 3):

Infura cannot (and should not) host a private key for you. It would be their ether and not yours. :)

If you want to work with local keys and Infura, check out the `eth-account` library, which has [`eth_account.Account.create()`](http://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eth_account.html#eth_account.account.Account.create):

```
>>> from eth_account import Account
>>> acct = Account.create('KEYSMASH FJAFJKLDSKF7JKFDJ 1530')
>>> acct.address
'0x5ce9454909639D2D17A3F753ce7d93fa0b9aB12E'
>>> acct.privateKey
b"\xb2\}\xb3\x1f\xee\xd9\x12''\xbf\t9\xdcv\x9a\x96VK-\xe4\xc4rm\x03[6\xec\xf1\xe5\xb3d"

# These methods are also available: signHash(), signTransaction(), encrypt()
# They correspond to the same-named methods in Account.*
# but without the private key argument
```

Once you've created an account locally, you can [sign the transaction locally and broadcast it](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-transaction):

```
>>> transaction = {
...     'to': '0xF0109fC8DF283027b6285cc889F5aA624EaC1F55',
...     'value': 1000000000,
...     'gas': 2000000,
...     'gasPrice': 234567897654321,
...     'nonce': 0,
...     'chainId': 1
... }
>>> key = '0x4c0883a69102937d6231471b5dbb6204fe5129617082792ae468d01a3f362318'
>>> signed = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction, key)
>>> signed.rawTransaction
HexBytes('0xf86a8086d55698372431831e848094f0109fc8df283027b6285cc889f5aa624eac1f55843b9aca008025a009ebb6ca057a0535d6186462bc0b465b561c94a295bdb0621fc19208ab149a9ca0440ffd775ce91a833ab410777204d5341a6f9fa91216a6f3ee2c051fea6a0428')
>>> signed.hash
HexBytes('0xd8f64a42b57be0d565f385378db2f6bf324ce14a594afc05de90436e9ce01f60')
>>> signed.r
4487286261793418179817841024889747115779324305375823110249149479905075174044
>>> signed.s
30785525769477805655994251009256770582792548537338581640010273753578382951464
>>> signed.v
37

# When you run sendRawTransaction, you get back the hash of the transaction:
>>> w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)  
'0xd8f64a42b57be0d565f385378db2f6bf324ce14a594afc05de90436e9ce01f60'
```